# Is it possible to forward the metrics information of Azure Service Bus into Azure Application Insights?

Tags: azureservicebus, azure-application-insights

I use Azure Service Bus Queues extensively. And I am planning to use Azure Application Insights for monitoring Queues and to generate alerts.

Is there a way to pass the metric information of Azure SB Queue into Application Insights ?

Any other alternative approach ?

Thanks

Prabath

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to monitor the Queue based on Count of Messages in a Queue, Incoming Messages, Outgoing Messages, etc with the help of the latest [Azure Monitor Metrics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/monitoring-and-diagnostics/monitoring-supported-metrics?redirectedfrom=MSDN#microsoftservicebusnamespaces). You can make use of the [Azure Monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/monitoring-and-diagnostics/monitoring-overview-azure-monitor) in Azure portal, which allows you to configure dashboards and alerts.

[Application insights](https://azure.microsoft.com/documentation/services/application-insights/) is for diagnosing problems with web apps, for Service Bus monitoring you should go with [Azure Monitor](https://azure.microsoft.com/services/monitor/).

Comment: Thanks Arun for your comments. I will look into the potentials of Azure Monitor as well.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use Application Insights for pass the metric information of Azure SB queue.

Application Insights is used with below services:

•   Web apps on an IIS server - on-premises or in a VM

•   Java web apps

•   Node.js apps

•   Web apps on Azure

•   Cloud Services on Azure

•   App servers running in Docker

•   Single-page web apps

•   Sharepoint

•   Windows desktop app

•   Other platforms

Service Bus metrics gives you the state of resources in your Azure subscription. With a rich set of metrics data, you can assess the overall health of your Service Bus resources, not only at the namespace level, but also at the entity level. These statistics can be important as they help you to monitor the state of Service Bus.

For more details, refer “[Azure Service Bus metrics in Azure Monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-metrics-azure-monitor)”.